# 3rd Party Libraries

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Is posible to use 3rd Party Libraries in the plugins like opencv (I tried to used but I don't have any problems compiling but when I tried to execute the program I have problems finding the simbols) or are there any way to get the image from the camera executing my program not a plugin.

Thanks.

Álex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/31/3rd-party-libraries/) by [Alejandro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36/alejandro/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should be able to use any third party library. For example the gazebo_ros plugins are plugins to Gazebo that use ROS libraries.

Can you create a simple standalone application that links against opencv and also executes?

You can also check your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, which should contain the path to the opencv library.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0